# Problem setting up Zend Framework to run with Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, zend

I am trying to get Zend Framework working with netbeans, but every time there is the error

`"php.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I am using WAMP server 2.0
it is installed in e:\wamp

My Zend framework is inside e:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.10.5

I have located the ZendFramework script as:  E:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.10.5\bin\zf.bat

I am also registered the module.

What am i doing wrong?

I am running on Windows 7 32 bit, using NETbean 6.9 RC1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `E:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.10.5\bin\zf.bat` is trying to execute `php.exe`. This is probably in the `E:\wamp\bin\php` folder. <del>Move the contents of `e:\wamp\www\ZendFramework-1.10.5` to `E:\wamp\bin\php` or try editing the batch file (`zf.bat`) with notepad to change the command that executes `php.exe` so that it points to the right path.</del>

Check this out: http://samsami2u.wordpress.com/2008/07/18/phpexe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: thanks philia, I was banging my head for hours due to this

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the bin directory containing 'php.exe' to your windows path. To do this (on Windows 7):

1. Click Start button, right-click Computer, open properties.
2. Select 'Advanced system setting'.
3. Click 'Environment Variables' button.
4. In 'System variables' section, select the 'Path' variable and click 'Edit...' button below.
5. Append to the end of the text the following (for default wampsever setup, may be different for other setups)(without the quotes) ";C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0"
6. Click OK a few times to close all the windows you just opened.
7. Relax and get a brew, you're done :)